# Removal of admin rights from each desktop using C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry, regedit

How should i remove admin rights for each desktop user on Win XP, Win Vista and Win 7 programmatically using C# .NET ?

Comment: Can't we remove admin rights of a user programmatically using C#, .NET

Comment: what's wrong with the command shell?

Comment: why the obsession with c# when plain old shell gets the job done. There's always group policy too.

Comment: @David ya you are right but i want this functionality as a part of some project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with a cmd prompt.

With the NET GROUP Command, you can remove the admin-group from the user-group.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754051%28WS.10%29.aspx

http://ss64.com/nt/net_useradmin.html

best regards

Comment: Thanks but i want to know how it can be done in C# .NET programmatically.

Comment: you can run the shell-command in c# with System.Diagnostics.Process - more info: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/wincmdline.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could P/Invoke [NetGroupDelUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370427.aspx); not sure if there is a .NET equivalent.